# Can I select items from inventory while moving?

Tags: dont-starve

Is it intended that while moving with the keyboard (WASD) that I can't select or interact with my inventory? I can do it with the mouse when I click on a location, but can't seem to do it while moving with WASD.

Edit: To specify, I'm moving with WASD, clicking on my inventory, and the game is not registering the click. Mouse is not a touchpad.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not intended

I just started Don't Starve to double check: **I can move around with WASD and meanwhile use my mouse to browse through the inventory.** During crafting, you have to stand still (moving cancels the crafting).

Comment: I do this all the time as well, especially when night is closing in and I want to have a campfire ready.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really a feature of the game that a keyboard can't handle many keys pressed at the same time.If you're moving diagonal, up and right and want to eat something in your inventory you'll have three keys pressed at the same time.

Every time I've played it, it's using the mouse to select a place to move to, and while on the way there you can pick up items from your inventory or right click on them to equip / use them.

Edit:

Also [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6669/how-do-i-remove-the-limit-on-pc-keyboard-button-presses) deals with the issue if you really want to use the wsad keys to move while using items. (I'd still recommend getting use to the mouse or a game pad though)

Comment: Hi Mikey,

I edited the post above. I am not trying to use my inventory items via keyboard, but am using the keyboard to move my character and use items via my mouse.