# Keyboard stopped detecting multiple keypresses

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, hardware, keyboard

I have been playing CSGO on my Lenovo Ideapad 300-15isk for more than two years. Few days back when I was playing CSGO multiple keypresses stopped working. It still detects two keys pressed at once. But, it is not detecting more than two keys. Now I can't move diagonally while shooting or I can't shoot while crouch moving. This is really annoying and the game is almost unplayable. What could be the reason behind it and how to fix it?

Comment: Use keyboard testing software to test if your keyboard is working properly: https://alternativeto.net/software/aqua-s-keytest/

Comment: Hi @galacticninja, I checked my keyboard. Earlier I used to use T,F,G and H key for movement. So, now multiple keypresses with those buttons is not working. But, when I checked with W,A,S,D keys its working fine. How is this possible?

Comment: If the TFGH keys were working for more than two years, but just stopped working recently, then it might be due to physical damage to the keyboard. If you've just tried TFGH recently, then it might be due to hardware limitation on the keyboard. See [How do I remove the limit on PC keyboard button presses?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/6669/4797)

Comment: @galacticninja your comments were more helpful

Comment: Were the TFGH keys working fine for more than two years previously, or were those keys something you just tried recently?

Comment: Yes TFGH keys were working fine. I have played for 2 years using those keys.