# I cannot use Shift+W+1 at the same time

Tags: keyboard, first-person-shooter

I recently bought a new desktop and it came with a wired keyboard to use. However, whenever I play an FPS game, whenever I try to press 1 while using Shift+W it does not do anything. This is extremely annoying and it only happens with this combination of inputs in particular. How can I fix this?

Comment: Does this only happen in a particular game or for any application? You can test this using this keyboard rollover test tool: http://gadzikowski.com/nkeyrollover.html

Comment: It happens for all applications. What is weird is if I do, say, Shift+W+2 it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove the limit on PC keyboard button presses?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6669/how-do-i-remove-the-limit-on-pc-keyboard-button-presses)