# Can't press 2 arrow keys + specefic letter keys at the same time

Tags: keyboard

As the title states, I can't press the specefic arrow keys right + up at the same time in combination with some letter keys, not all letters, just some.

I'm playing a videogame and I wish to move diagonaly top right (right arrow + up arrow) and press the <kbd>R</kbd> or <kbd>S</kbd> key on my keyboard. My keybord won't let me. I've read online that it could be a hardware problem. I own a Roccat FX gaming keyboard and other combinations of diagonal movement + letter keys works, just specefically not those I want.

I CAN'T press right arrow + up arrow + <kbd>R</kbd>, as well as same combination + <kbd>S</kbd> or + <kbd>B</kbd>. While I CAN press right arrow + up arrow + <kbd>Q</kbd> or + <kbd>W</kbd> keys. As well as the opposite left arrow + up arrow + <kbd>R</kbd>, + <kbd>S</kbd> or + <kbd>B</kbd> works fine, just not the right arrow?

A bit confusing haha, fyi all my keys works on their own, so no single dead keys.

Any idea why I specefically can't press my desired combination while the opposite works and some keys work and some not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove the limit on PC keyboard button presses?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6669/how-do-i-remove-the-limit-on-pc-keyboard-button-presses)

Comment: Sounds like a hardware limitation, consider buying a new keyboard that doesn't have an input limit.